# JabRef differences in [shorttitle] between versions 3.8.1 and 4.1, not discounting ‘the’, ‘a’, ‘an’, 'of' in titles

Tags: bibtex, jabref

I am working with two versions of JabRef on two windows machine. If I have a title "A paper on the workings of the world" that I want to generate a BibTeX key for in JabRef using the `[shorttitle]` key pattern I get two different results. For version 3.8.1 I get a BibTex key of:

"paperworkingsworld"

and on version 4.1 I get

"apaperof"

In both cases, I have `[shorttitle]` as my default patterns in JabRef. How can I get version 4.1 to discount the unimportant works like it does in version 3.8.1? I don't want to just update everything to 4.1 as then I won't be able to generate the BibTeX keys in the style I want.

Comment: Did you asked the jabref support? Seems to be an pure jabref question ...

Comment: Hi, you should  probably  use `[veryshorttitle]` that discounts the words like `a, the,...` http://help.jabref.org/en/BibtexKeyPatterns
Edit// Btw, JabRef 4.2 has been released recently

Comment: Reading http://help.jabref.org/en/BibtexKeyPatterns#title-related-key-patterns, `veryshorttitle` returns the first word of the title only. I would propose that an issue is opened at https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues to bring back the old behavior of `shorttitle` as for my academic experience, there is a good reason to drop the filler words.